# Uploaded Media Images on Site

Tags: images, customization

If I delete  uploaded images from my media file, will this delete them from the actual blogs?

Comment: What do you mean with "media file"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [deleting from your Media Library](https://en.support.wordpress.com/media/deleting-files/), then yes, once they're deleted from your Media Library, they won't show up in your posts or pages any more—unless cached in some way by search engines and so forth.